# is it possible to know which user disconnects in websocket node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I want to know which user disconnects websocket node js, I have managed to display a message if there is a user disconnected from the server, but not knowing who is disconnected. this is my simple code

```
var server = require('ws').Server;
var s = new server({ port:5001 });
s.on('connection',function(ws){
    ws.on('message',function(message){
        console.log("Receive : "+ message);
        ws.send(message);
    });
    ws.on('close',function(){
        console.log("i lose a client");
    });
    console.log("1 more client connected");
});
```

Comment: I think this depends on the way you perform client authentication and where you store the data. During client authentication, you can (should be able to) add logic that attaches the user data to the specific web socket connection object (i.e. `ws.user = user_data`)... this will allow you access to the user data throughout the connection's lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

The socket (*ws*) has an id:

```
s.on('connection',function(ws){
    ws.on('message',function(message){
       console.log("Receive : " + message + " from " + ws.id);
       ws.send(message);
    });
    ws.on('close',function(){
        console.log("i lose client" + ws.id);
    });
    console.log(ws.id + " connected");
});
```

Comment: I have tried it and I got the message "Receive message from undefined", how it is defined.